# "К чёртовой матери" — нужны запятые или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В указанном ниже тексте "к чёртовой матери" нужно выделять запятыми или нет?

*Я бы даже ждать не стала, а вещички бы собрала и умотала бы со своим другом **к чёртовой матери** побыстрее в Израиль.*

Answer (score 2):

В "Фразеологическом словаре русского языка" указано, что оборот "к чёртовой матери" может быть в роли обстоятельства или междометия.
У вас в предложении и так имеется обстоятельство: *умотала бы **(куда?)** в Израиль*, поэтому "к чёртовой матери" я считаю междометием. Следовательно, его **требуется выделить запятыми**.
Сравните два примера из Нацкорпуса:

- Я уже говорил, что на первых порах своей карьеры в НХЛ мне хотелось
  все бросить и уехать к чертовой матери.
- Люди думали: какой, к чертовой матери, теннис?

Возможна и такая трактовка: *"...умотала бы к чёртовой матери — в Израиль"*: в этом случае Израиль позиционируется как место обитания упомянутой родительницы чёрта.